# why can't I see the extra line when I directly open the csv file?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python on Windows and I met a problem when creating a csv file.
Here is the code

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["trasaction_id", "product_id", "price"])
    writer.writerow([1000, 1, 5])
```

When I open data.csv in VSCode, I get an extra line:

```
trasaction_id,product_id,price

1000,1,5
```

I know this problem can be solved by adding `newline=""` in the open() function. But I don't understand why I can't see the extra line when I directly open this file with Notepad?

Comment: New line in Linux and Windows are different. Most modern app support both, but Notepad only show the Windows one. Your code might create a new line in the Linux one.

Comment: Also, close the `writer.writerow([1000, 1, 5]`.

Comment: @BrainFl Thanks, but I wrote this code using VSCode on Windows so I still don't understand why I got this.